# Crontab cannot find program installed in local user's bin dir

Tags: user-accounts, path, crontab

I am trying to run a bash script on a dreamhost account that does some backup operations. The program I use to do the backup is installed in the home directory of the web hosting account under `~/usr/local/bin/`. That path is exported in both my `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files. And when I run the script from the bash command line, it all goes well.

When, however, I install the script in the crontab for the user using the following command:

```
crontab -e -u <user>
```

The crontab log reports that the program I use to to do the backup cannot be found. I've checked using `whoami` and the crontab is in fact being run as , so I'm not sure why it's unable to locate the program's binary. Any thoughts?

Comment: What happens if you just use `crontab -e`?  If you are actually trying to edit another users crontab, you won't be able to do that on dreamhost's shared hosting (although you may be able to on VPS or dedicated, I don't know why you would want to tho)

Comment: That's not the issue here. I am just running the crontab command with -u to be explicit. Running without has the same effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamhost seems to have a special limited execution environment for crontab's. Reffering to [this page](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Crontab#Execution_Environment) of dreamhosts wiki on crontab execution environment:

"Due to security concerns, DreamHost cron does NOT execute with a normal environment."

"The PATH environment variable is simply /usr/bin:/bin, and the SHELL is set to /bin/sh.  You must specify the full path to all commands not in the default PATH, and always specify the full path for files. "

(more text and examples exist at the source link, I only copy/pasted the most relevant sentences.)